# Camel Java DSL: Update the next polling request param using the value from the response

Tags: apache, apache-camel, camel-http, camel-jackson

I am new to Apache camel, this is what I am trying to figure out. In a sample code below, I am trying to use the property - "value" in the request param in next polling request.

```
String valueFromTheResponse= ""
m.addRouteBuilder(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("timer://foo?period=2)
            .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
            .setHeader("Accept", constant("application/json"))
            .to("https4://" + <myrequestURL>?param=<valueFromTheResponse>)
            .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
            .setProperty("value", jsonpath("$.value"))
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    valueFromTheResponse = (String) exchange.getProperty("value");
                }
            })
        }
    });
    m.run();
```

What would be the best way to achieve this? or assign the class level variable the property value?

UPDATE: SOLUTION
got it working by adding the following:

```
.process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    exchange.getIn().setHeader("CamelHttpQuery", buildParamQuery());
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to store the value in a shared field in for example the `RouteBuilder` class itself, or a shared class instance. And then in the *to http* endpoint uri, you need to set the param query as a message header instead where you can get that value via a method call.

```
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, method(this, "buildParamQuery"))
```

And then have a method

```
public String buildParamQuery() {
  return "param=" + sharedValue;
}
```

And then you set this field from the inlined processor with the last value. And mind about the initial value, eg the first poll the value is `null` so you need to maybe to return an empty string/null from the `buildParamQuery` method or something else.

Comment: method(this, "buildParamQuery") gave me a NPE, BUT I was able to use your suggested way by  doing this .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, simple(buildParamQuery())). 
Looks like the problem is still the same, buildParamQuery() is only called once and not in the next polling request. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I somehow need to update the CamelHttpQuery for the next poll.